# is it possible to change aws s3 access denied message with nginx 403 forbidden

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I am using DigitalOcean Spaces. How do I change the XML access denied page to Nginx 403 forbidden page

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SawNX.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

In [this example configuration for a S3 Gateway](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-s3-gateway/blob/master/common/etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template#L103), S3 API 403 errors get rewritten to 404 errors. You could possibly modify the configuration so that you could present NGINX 403 errors instead of 404 errors as the example uses.